# Visual Studio 2012 crashing when pasting large text from clipboard

Tags: visual-studio-2012, text, intellisense, copy-paste, freeze

I'm trying to paste a large text file that is pre-parsed to fit in an array declaration

```
public static void Items[] test = new Items[] {
    //Large text goes here
    new Items("Text", "Text")
};
```

When I paste this text, which is about 70K lines, VS2012 just crashes. It's probably still working in the background, but I'd rather not wait.

I think the best solution would be to temporarily disable Intellisense before pasting, but then what happens when it's turned back on? And how do I disable it in the first place?

Is there another reason?

Comment: Maybe the approach is wrong. 70000 record should be stored in some kind a database. At least as xml file.

Comment: Do you have any add-in's? Have you tried disabling them, or using safe mode? And if you're pasting 70,000 lines, could you use a plain text editor like Notepad?

Comment: I have that same problem when pasting some fixture responses. If they are somewhat big, it crashes, I've even waited for 10min, but no luck, I've had to kill the process.